# Change max. idle time for (crypto) handshake in Chromium HTTP/3

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, cronet

Background: I'm trying to measure common metrics (e.g. firstContentfulPaint) using selenium with chromium over satellite links under different loss and delay parameters.

Problem: When running with high delay / loss rates, chromium stops the handshake relatively early with this error message: **No recent network activity after 4001103us.** (The exact number of microseconds changes but is always equal to between 4 and 5 seconds).

Found out so far:
This error message seems to be generated here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/third_party/quiche/src/quic/core/quic_connection.cc;l=6323?q=%22No%20recent%20network%20activity%20after%22&ss=chromium

I believe the relevant variable is: **quic_max_idle_time_before_crypto_handshake_seconds**

and is set here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/third_party/quiche/src/quic/core/quic_constants.h;l=139;drc=1b6e5b6710b7c002de308d7195326fc84d6e9b33

**Question / TL;DR**:

How do I change the timeout used by chromium during the handshake stage in HTTP/3 / QUIC? (without building chromium from scratch)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: should be able to set "max_time_before_crypto_handshake_seconds" and    "max_idle_time_before_crypto_handshake_seconds" using "experimental options".   So something like prefs.put("max_time_before_crypto_handshake_seconds", 10);  options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);   (prefs is a hashmap in Java)  The config constants are here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/components/cronet/url_request_context_config.cc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately there seems to be no option to set these in prefs. As far as I know all available options are here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

I did try out your suggestion but I didn't work.